# Wait for multiple separate promises to resolve

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, events, angular-promise

i have angular promises across different controllers, and i want to execute function once all of them have been finished.

Is there any way like via events or promises to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the documentation for `$q`, in particular `$q.all()`.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: but i have promises across different controllers, i cannot use q.all

Comment: You're going to have to have a single place where you can detect when your various promises resolve. A factory is a decent way to communicate among controllers. But it really depends on your use case, there may be a better way. Edit your question with some code and I can be of more help.

Answer (score 2):

Angular documentation makes it very clear how to share data and methods across controllers.... [services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) (and factories)

If you find yourself needing to coordinate multiple controllers, it's an indication that you need a service. Services are there to help with exactly this type of situation (and more).

Take a look at this Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/PXVL8YA3lOk7beSvVe5E?p=preview
and be sure to open the console so you can see the log messages.

Method D of the service will not execute until Methods A-C are resolved.

```
MyService.$inject = ['$q', '$timeout'];
function MyService($q, $timeout) {
  var MyService = this;

  var deferredA = $q.defer();
  var deferredB = $q.defer();
  var deferredC = $q.defer();

  // go ahead and call method D right away
  // it won't fire until all the other methods have completed
  methodD(); 

  MyService.methodA = function() {
    $timeout(function() {
      deferredA.resolve();
      console.log("Method A end!");
    }, 1000);
    console.log("Method A begin!");
  };

  MyService.methodB = function() {
    $timeout(function() {
      deferredB.resolve();
      console.log("Method B end!");
    }, 1000);
    console.log("Method B begin!");
  };

  MyService.methodC = function() {
   $timeout(function() {
      deferredC.resolve();
      console.log("Method C end!");
    }, 1000);
    console.log("Method C begin!");
  };

  function methodD() {
    $q.all([deferredA.promise, deferredB.promise, deferredC.promise]).then(function() {
      console.log("Method D called!");

      // reset all the promises and call method D again
      deferredA = $q.defer();
      deferredB = $q.defer();
      deferredC = $q.defer();
      methodD();
    });
  }
}
```

Each controller can call the service at any point in time. Method D will only execute once all controllers have called in, and their respective promises have been resolved.

```
  Ctrl1.$inject = ['$scope', 'MyService'];
  function Ctrl1($scope, MyService) {
    $scope.go = function() {
      MyService.methodA();
    };
  }

  Ctrl2.$inject = ['$scope', 'MyService'];
  function Ctrl2($scope, MyService) {
    $scope.go = function() {
      MyService.methodB();
    };
  }

  Ctrl3.$inject = ['$scope', 'MyService'];
  function Ctrl3($scope, MyService) {
    $scope.go = function() {
      MyService.methodC();
    };
  }
```